# Python 3 attach to running process with PID

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, subprocess

I have some code that uses subprocess.Popen to execute a command, script, etc.  I have been looking for a way to reattach to the underlying process to continue monitoring it if the parent python script ended unexpectedly. We have this code running on both Linux and Windows. We would have the PID and we would be trying to reattach to the process as the same user that started the process.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "attach"? The problem is fundamentally OS-dependent, and unrelated to Python really. A debugger could let you observe the internal state of the process and so on, but it's probably not realistically possible (or at least not easy) to reconnect its standard output etc to another process.

Comment: Thanks @triple. Honestly that is what I was aiming for.  To reattach to the stdout/sterr file descriptors, but also to know if/when it finished.  I grab the PID at the beginning and redirect out/err to files too so I at least am able to investigate it in this manner.  Looks like a better way in Python is not possible.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I guess you could redirect to a FIFO and then connect some other process to that FIFO subsequently, or run the process under `tmux` or `screen` on Linux. On Windows, nothing is ever easy, but I guess you know that.